# Generate keys on smartcard with given exponent

Tags: c++, cryptography

I am generating keys on a smartcard with **OpenSC**. Is it possible to specify a certain exponent to use? Currently I am calling `sc_pkcs15init_generate_key()` to generate the key pair. But I did not find a way to set the exponent.
I am aware, that it is possible to generate the key with a given exponent on the PC, but I do not want to do that for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

- Not all smart cards are happy with the exponents you'd like to use, even when importing existing keys.
- There is no uniform way of passing in the exponent for the newly generated key in OpenSC, AFAIK/AFAIS.